# the right regex for catching a part of url

Tags: javascript, regex

There are some cases of URLs like below.

```
(1) https://m.aaa.kr/category/outer/55/
(2) https://m.aaa.kr/category/inner/5/
(3) https://m.aaa.kr/product/jacket/3031/category/55/display/1/
(4) https://m.aaa.kr/product/shirts/30/category/5/display/1/
```

I need the right regex for catching the "55" or "5" part of those URLs.

What I tried was `/(?:\/category\/\w+)(\/category\/)|(\d+[^\/])/g`

However, this regex also catches the "3031" in case (3), "30" in case (4).
And it cannot catch "5" in cases (2) and (4).

How can I fix it to do the right?

Comment: try `category\D+\K(\d+)` check [here](https://regex101.com/r/wfZif0/1)

Comment: So in essence you need the first number after the string "/category"?

Comment: @Onyambu it doesn't catch anything.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica in general, yes

Comment: Check the link. I am not quite sure which engine you are using, but the regex provided uses perl engine and it does capute the values

Comment: What is the environment where you are using a regex?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sorry, I didn't think about it. I am using it in JavaScript.

Comment: Does https://jsfiddle.net/wiktor_stribizew/cgozkjw8/ work for you? See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/S89Qxa/2). Or, https://jsfiddle.net/wiktor_stribizew/cgozkjw8/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that your `/(?:\/category\/\w+)(\/category\/)|(\d+[^\/])/g` regex match multiple occurrences (due to `g` flag) of the pattern that matches either `/category/`, then one or more word chars, and then `/category/` (captured into Group 1) **or** captures into Group 2 one or more digits *and then one char other than a `/`*. This is definitely a wrong pattern, as you only want to match and capture *digits* in Group 2. Also, the first alternative does not seem to match anything meaningful for you at all, as it does not restrict the second alternative.

Also, using `\w+` to match any text between two slashes is not usually efficient as the URL parts often contain `-` chars, that are not word chars.

So, what you can use is one of

```js
/\/category\/(?:[\w-]+\/)?(\d+)/
/\/category\/(?:[^\/]+\/)?(\d+)/
```

Note there is no `g` flag since all you need is the first match. *Details*:

- `\/category\/` - a `/category/` string
- `(?:[\w-]+\/)?` - an optional sequence of one or more word or hyphen chars and then a `/` (note `[^\/]+` matches any one or more chars other than `/`, and also a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3512471/3832970) that helps keep the match object structure simpler)
- `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits.

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
const urls = ['https://m.aaa.kr/category/outer/55/','https://m.aaa.kr/category/inner/5/','https://m.aaa.kr/product/jacket/3031/category/55/display/1/','https://m.aaa.kr/product/shirts/30/category/5/display/1/']
const rx = /\/category\/(?:[\w-]+\/)?(\d+)/;
for (const url of urls) {
    document.body.innerHTML += '"' + url + '" => "<b>' + (rx.exec(url) || ['',''])[1] + '</b>"<br/>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about catching the first digit (or digits) directly after `/category/` or `/category/someothertext/`

with: `/\/category\/(\w+\/)?(\d+)/g`

You can test it online here: https://regex101.com/r/n4dj1r/1

Comment: In that way, there is no way I can get only the numbers like 55, 5. I just need those numbers. And because the "someothertext" is always different, I must use regex.

Comment: Try `\/category\/[^\d]*(\d+)`: Find /category/, skip everything after that that's not a number, if present, and then capture the number (that's the first number after "category"). In sed terms, ` sed 's-.*category[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\).*-\1-g'`. See https://regex101.com/r/ABUWyA/1.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica  I used it in JavaScript and it captures the category number with ``regex.exec(URL)``. I thought I might eliminate the words 'category' but ``regex.exec`` just brings the number as the array's second value. For now, it seems like it's working well. Thanks.